# Can we distribute ipa file signed with Enterprise developer program on Testflight?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

What I learned from forums that a build can be marked for testing from iTunes Connect and it will be available on TestFlight, but from Enterprise developer program we don't have access to iTunesConnect.

So is there any way to distribute your enterprise build using Testflight?

Is there any backdoor entry for TestFlight?

Comment: With Enterprise account... you can't....

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: **No**

Enteprise generated builds assume that the app will be distribute through a MDM solution, otherwise your users will have to manually drag and drop the IPA and trust the certificate used to sign the app.

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html) in the section: **Exporting Your App In-House**

There are plenty of MDM solutions from all kind of prices and ranges.